# PHP build fails: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: github, github-actions

I tried to build some simple PHP code in GitHub actions but it failed with a missing file or directory error:

> Error: require(/home/runner/work/deneme-github/deneme-github/vendor/composer/../../bootstrap/helpers.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Here's the workflow file:

```yaml
name: PHP Composer

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Validate composer.json and composer.lock
      run: composer validate

    - name: Cache Composer packages
      id: composer-cache
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: vendor
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-php-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-php-
    - name: Install dependencies
      if: steps.composer-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      run: composer update --no-scripts --lock --ignore-platform-reqs && composer update && composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-suggest --with-all-dependencies && composer --no-autoloader
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Which step threw that error?

Comment: install dependencies step